# Safari user installed fonts don't render

Tags: fonts, safari, font-face, font-family

I am using MAC OSX and my Safari version is 13.0.3. I tried installing some custom fonts into my machine. I installed the font great-vibes from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/popular (just an example) on my machine and it now shows under User Font section in my Font Book. I am using .otf format of the font. I now tried using it on my web application like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes'; //Added postscript name as well, did not work
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Great Vibes')
}
body {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes' !important;
}
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox (even without the @font-face) declaration. But this is **NOT** working on Safari. I have tried options like  -webkit-text-stroke: .5px; text-rendering:optimizeLegibility; but it does not work. I tried installing different custom fonts into my machine and they don't work on Safari either. I see that the font has been installed correctly.

NOTE: Keeping the custom font within my application code and using @font-face/src/url works just fine. The issue is when trying to access custom installed fonts on the machine.

Answer (score 20):

The reason for this is that Safari 12/macOS Mojave disabled display of user-installed fonts [to combat browser fingerprinting](https://gizmodo.com/apple-declares-war-on-browser-fingerprinting-the-sneak-1826549108), which enables online tracking through observing your system configuration—including which fonts you have installed. By only rendering the default system fonts, and of course any other internet-accessible font, your computer looks more like any other and becomes harder to track.

If you want to develop in Safari using a non-standard font, you have to use a `@font-face`/`src`/`url` declaration pointing to an embedded or internet-hosted font. Alternatively, you can disable the tracking protection, but that's probably not a good idea.

If you have enhanced tracking protection activated in Firefox, which also blocks fingerprinting, you should see the same behavior as Safari.

Sources: two [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/cborfg/safari_wont_display_userinstalled_local_fonts/) [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/9jp5m3/psa_safari_12_disablednerfed_setting_custom_fonts/)

Comment: It is maddening that there isn't a `defaults.write` for this or a preference to allow this!

Comment: You said, 'Alternatively, you can disable the tracking protection'. How do you do that? Unticking 'Prevent cross-site tracking' does not seem to restore the ability to display local installed fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/), where the basic syntax for local fonts looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Graublau Web';
src: url(GraublauWeb.eot);
src: local('Graublau Web Regular'), url(GraublauWeb.otf) format('opentype');
}
```

Comment: I am using .otf format of the font. As mentioned I don't want to use the attribute "url" as I am not maintaining the fonts on my application code. I am trying to access the fonts installed on my system. I did try src: local('Great Vibes') format('opentype') and it does not work.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I must have misunderstood. Please see my edited answer. For further explanation, refer to the link I posted. :)