# How to use downloaded fonts on MacOS and iOS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to use a downloaded font on MacOS and iOS in Safari. There are many war stories out there about bulletproof CSS and such, but I haven't found the correct incantation. Here's my best effort, and I've tried many variations with different quoting, casing and so on. The font is called AHRDIcons, and it's installed and working on both operating systems. That's all I need---I don't need a web font, I just want something that will work on systems that have the font already available.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AHRDIcons;
    src:         local(AHRDIcons);
    src:         url("AHRDIcons.ttf") format("truetype");
    src:         url("file:/Library/Fonts/AHRDIcons.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

This works on MacOS if the page is loaded locally (as file:///Users/.../cup.html), and this is because of the 3rd src option. It doesn't work on MacOS or iOS if the file is served by http (as http://.../.../cup.html), which I would expect to work using one of the first 2 srcs. But instead there are just little squares.

Comment: Checking Develop -> 'Disable local file restrictions' makes no difference.

Comment: Hey can u check this and tell if it helps https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Comment: This is all about web fonts. Maybe I'll have to use a web font if I can't get a local font to work, but it seems like a lot of overhead for what should (?) be a more simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion: I don't think this is possible. Maybe there are defaults writes that would permit it, or maybe the whole fingerprint-detection could be turned off, but as I continue to read about this issue here and on other sites, I haven't found anything to lead me along those lines. And not sure I would do them anyway.

I solved the problem by hosting the ttf on the server, and using a src: url("http://.../../AHRDIcons.ttf") clause in the font-face declaration.

Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

If the font is already installed on the operating system and your only users are going to be on said operating system, then you don't need to add it with `font-face` at all.

Double click the `ttf` in OSX, click the 'info preview mode' icon and check what the font's family is. Then just use that in your CSS:

Here's an example with Apple Symbols:

```
p {
   font-family:"Apple Symbols";
}
```

Comment: Alas, no. Thanks for the answer, but this is where I started this journey. I believe this fails because Safari limits fonts by default to prevent fingerprinting, as described in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986432/safari-user-installed-fonts-dont-render